# Can't get post ajax request data python

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, forms, python-2.7

I have html form:

```
    <form id = "contactForm">
        <input type="text" name="name"></input>
        <input  type="text" name="phone"></input>
    </form>
```

I have Button and when I click it I am doing ajax post request:

```
$.post( "/send-form", $('#contactForm').serialize()
```

In chrome web inspector
I can see that data is sent
name=+gfdsfd&phone=89999[image]

This is my backend function I am using Flask,Python:

```
  @app.route("/send-form", methods=['POST'])
def send_form():
    name = phone = email = country = text = None
    data = request.data
    print request.data
```

And it prints empty string in my console.
What can be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access Flask's form data you should use the **form** attribute of the request object .

```
name=request.form['name']
data=request.form['phone']
```

Comment: Thanks god I've broken my brain trying to detect what's wrong!

Comment: But I still have a question. I used the wrong syntaxis above in my answer  in another project and it worked.How can that be?

Comment: Could you post this 'other project' details ?

Comment: wait a few seconds I will make another question with details and post a link here