# python get form data how can this be?

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

This is my js function for ajax form submit:

```
$('.sendButton').on('click', function(){
    $.post( "/send-form", $('#contactForm').serialize())
}
```

This is my form:

```
<form id="contactForm">
    <input id="fastName" name="name" type="text" />
    <input id="fastPhone" name="phone" type="text" />
    <div class="sendButton">send</div>
</form>
```

And this is my backend function to handle it, I am using python, flask

```
@app.route("/send-form", methods=['POST'])
def send_form():
    data = request.data   
    print request.data
```

And in my console it prints data:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Feb/2015 23:50:54] "POST /send-form HTTP/1.1" 200 - name=dfdsf&phone=89920203725
```

But I did the same in another project and it prints nothing.
Details are here:
[Can't get post ajax request data python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28661576/cant-get-post-ajax-request-data-python/28661744?noredirect=1#comment45618706_28661744)
How can this be possible?

Answer (score 2):

The data is in the field request.form, and can be fetched by:

```
name = request.form['name']
phone = request.form['phone']
```

Remark. If they are not sent with, this code will throw an exception.

**Longer explanation**
The reason is that the data is sent using a encoding known as *application/x-www-form-urlencoded*. The data is in *request.data* field, but to decode it you can use *request.form*, and Flask will automatically decode it as *application/x-www-form-urlencoded*.