# Button type submit is not posting data

Tags: javascript, html, forms, django-views

I have a multistep register form where the entire form contains three parts. The user can click the next and previous buttons to toggle between them. The last button as usual is the button with type submit. However the button is not submitting the data. This is a django project. Below are the codes of the html, js file. I am also posting the codes of django view incase there is an error in that, that is causing the problem.

**html**

```
     <form method="POST">
                    
                    {% csrf_token %}

                    <!-- PERSONAL -->
                    
                    <div class="page slidepage">

                        <p class="form-title">PERSONAL DETAILS</p>

                        <div class="register-form-group">
                            <input class="register-form-control" type="text" id="full_name" name="full_name" maxlength="255" style="text-transform:uppercase" placeholder="name" required />
                            <label class="register-form-label" for="full_name">NAME</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="register-form-group">
                            <input class="register-form-control" type="tel" id="age" name="age" maxlength="2" pattern="[0-9]{10}" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" placeholder="age"  required />
                            <label class="register-form-label" for="age">YOUR AGE</label>
                        </div>


                        <div class="register-form-group">
                            <input class="register-form-control" type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" maxlength="10" pattern="[0-9]{10}" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" placeholder="phone no"  required />
                            <label class="register-form-label" for="phone">YOUR PHONE NUMBER</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="register-form-group">
                            <input class="register-form-control" type="text" id="address" name="address" maxlength="500" style="text-transform:uppercase" placeholder="address" required />
                            <label class="register-form-label" for="address">ADDRESS(Your pick-up and droping location)</label>
                        </div>

                

                        <div class="button-container">
                        
                            <button type="button" class="nav-btn nextbtn">Next &nbsp<i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i></button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <!-- END FOR PERSONAL DETAILS -->

                    <!-- PLANS -->
                    <div class="page">

                        <p class="form-title">PLANS</p>
                        
                        
                        <div class="plans">
                            
                            <input type="radio" name="plan" id="seven" value="7days">
                            <input type="radio" name="plan" id="fourteen" value="14days">
                            <input type="radio" name="plan" id="twentyone" value="21days">
                            
                            <label for="seven" class="seven">
                                <div class="dot"></div>
                                <div class="opt-text">7 Days</div>
                                <div class="opt-price"> <i class="fas fa-rupee-sign"></i>&nbsp2000</div>

                            </label>

                            <label for="fourteen" class="fourteen">
                                <div class="dot"></div>
                                <div class="opt-text">14 Days</div>
                                <div class="opt-price"> <i class="fas fa-rupee-sign"></i>&nbsp3500</div>

                            </label>

                            <label for="twentyone" class="twentyone">
                                <div class="dot"></div>
                                <div class="opt-text">21 Days</div>
                                <div class="opt-price"> <i class="fas fa-rupee-sign"></i>&nbsp5000</div>

                            </label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="button-container">
                        
                            <button type="button" class="nav-btn prev-1"><i class="fas fa-caret-left"></i> &nbsp Previous</button>

                            <button type="button" class="nav-btn next-2">Next &nbsp<i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- END FOR PLANS -->

                    <!-- LOGIN INFO -->
                    <div class="page">

                        <p class="form-title">LOGIN INFO</p>

                        <div class="register-form-group">
                            <input class="register-form-control" type="email" id="email" name="email"  placeholder="This will be your User ID" style="text-transform:lowercase" required />
                            <label class="register-form-label" for="email">YOUR EMAIL(This will become your UserId)</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="register-form-group">
                            <input class="register-form-control" type="password" id="password" name="password" maxlength="10" placeholder="max 10 characters" required />
                            <label class="register-form-label" for="password">PASSWORD (max 10 characters)</label>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="register-form-group">
                            <input class="register-form-control" type="password" id="con_password" name="con_password" maxlength="10" placeholder="confirm_password" required />
                        <label class="register-form-label" for="con_password">CONFIRM PASSWORD</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="button-container">
                        
                            <button type="button" class="nav-btn prev-3"><i class="fas fa-caret-left"></i> &nbsp Previous</button>

                            <button type="submit" class="submit next">REGISTER</button>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                    
                    <!-- END FOR LOGIN INFO -->
                
                </form>
```

**js**

```
const slidePage = document.querySelector(".slidepage");

const firstNextBtn = document.querySelector(".nextbtn");

const prevBtnSec = document.querySelector(".prev-1");

const nextBtnSec = document.querySelector(".next-2");


const prevBtnThird = document.querySelector(".prev-3");

const submitBtn = document.querySelector(".submit");

const progressText = document.querySelectorAll(".step p");

const progressCheck = document.querySelectorAll(".step .check");

const bullet = document.querySelectorAll(".step .bullet");

let max = 3;

let current = 1;








firstNextBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    slidePage.style.marginLeft = "-25%";
    bullet[current - 1].classList.add("active");
    progressText[current - 1].classList.add("active");
    progressCheck[current - 1].classList.add("active");
    current+=1;
});

prevBtnSec.addEventListener("click", function(){
    slidePage.style.marginLeft = "0%";
    bullet[current - 2].classList.remove("active");
    progressText[current - 2].classList.remove("active");
    progressCheck[current - 2].classList.remove("active");
    current-=1;
});

nextBtnSec.addEventListener("click", function(){
    slidePage.style.marginLeft = "-50%";
    bullet[current - 1].classList.add("active");
    progressText[current - 1].classList.add("active");
    progressCheck[current - 1].classList.add("active");
    current+=1;
});

submitBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){

    bullet[current - 1].classList.add("active");
    progressText[current - 1].classList.add("active");
    progressCheck[current - 1].classList.add("active");
    current+=1;
    // setTimeout(function(){

    // }, 800)
});

prevBtnThird.addEventListener("click", function(){
    slidePage.style.marginLeft = "-25%";
    bullet[current - 2].classList.remove("active");
    progressText[current - 2].classList.remove("active");
    progressCheck[current - 2].classList.remove("active");
    current-=1;
});
```

**views.py**

```
def registerpage(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        full_name = request.POST['full_name']
        age = request.POST['age']
        phone_no = request.PSOT['phone']
        address = request.POST['address']
        plan = request.POST['plan']
        email = request.POST['email']
        password1= request.POST['password']
        password2= request.POST['con_password']

        if password1==password2:
            user=CustomUser.objects.create_user(full_name=full_name,age=age, phone_no=phone_no, address=address, plan=plan, email=email, password=password1)
            user.save()
            print('user created')
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        return render(request, 'register.html')
```

This is the first time I am using a Custom user model, so i don't know if correctly creating the user. However the model is working fine as I created  a superuser with it.

** I made a simple form and it worked fine. i have not added "action" as I want the same page to process the data.** It seems that the above form is not working. Please point out my mistake.

Comment: Where is your "action" attribute of the form? And I cannot see anywhere you implemented sending data on a particular API.

Comment: @gaurav I was trying actually but even with the action attribute the data isn't getting posted. It seems the enitre form is not working

Comment: Even your code is having syntax errors.

Comment: @gaurav please point  my mistakes apart from the action, because adding the "action" is not making it work.

Comment: Try changing request.POST['....'] to request.form['....'] and let me know  your observations.

Comment: @gaurav i have edited the question, the backend code is working fine when  I tried it with a simple form and a submit button. So my observation is that the form that is posted here is not workin at all.

Comment: Try this code with simple form and if it works then make changes as per your need to implement it                                                      @app.route("/send-form", methods=['POST'])
def send_form():
    data = request.data   
    print request.data

Comment: Have a look and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28661930/python-get-form-data-how-can-this-be

Comment: @gaurav, thank you for the code, I have already tried with a simple form and it worked, the views.py is also correct. I think the js code is making some sort of interference with it.